# how to use php mail on fedora

Tags: php, email, fedora

I'm running fedora core 9 with php 5.2.6. I want to send a simple email from a form using the php mail command.

Do I need to configure my system to be an smtp server?  If so do I have to load something like pear?

I've read that pear is installed by default. however when I go to /usr/lib/php/pear , the folder is empty.

When I go to install pear with yum install php-pear none of the mirrors are available.

Does anyone have any suggesions on what mail service to use? If it's installed by default and where I can figure out how to configure.

Thanks!
Joe

This the code I'm using:

```
    <?php

require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

$mail->IsSMTP();

try {
  $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
  $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
  $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
  $mail->Port       = "587";                 // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
  $mail->Username   = "joestestemail@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
  $mail->Password   = "joeiscool";            // GMAIL password

  //This is the "Mail From:" field
  $mail->SetFrom('joestestemail@gmail.com', 'First Last');
  //This is the "Mail To:" field
  $mail->AddAddress('joe12345@mailcatch.com', 'John Doe');
  $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), advanced';
  $mail->Body     = "Hi! \n\n This is my first e-mail sent through PHPMailer.";

  $mail->Send();
  echo "Message Sent OK<p></p>\n";
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly recommend using a library like [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) to send emails.

You can use it with the server's own mail service or with any other server on the internet (your ISPs, Gmail, etc).

For a better idea, check [this example](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=exampleasmtp) from their website:

```
require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer(true); // the true param means it will throw exceptions on     errors, which we need to catch

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP

try {
  $mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // SMTP server
  $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
  $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
  $mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // sets the SMTP server
  $mail->Port       = 26;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
  $mail->Username   = "yourname@yourdomain"; // SMTP account username
  $mail->Password   = "yourpassword";        // SMTP account password
  $mail->AddReplyTo('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->AddAddress('whoto@otherdomain.com', 'John Doe');
  $mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->AddReplyTo('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), advanced';
  $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!';     // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
  $mail->MsgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'));
  $mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer.gif');      // attachment
  $mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.gif'); // attachment
  $mail->Send();
  echo "Message Sent OK<p></p>\n";
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
```

---

### Edit:

Following up on your comment..
For a simple GMail example, try this:

```
require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

$mail->IsSMTP();

try {
  $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
  $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
  $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
  $mail->Port       = 587;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
  $mail->Username   = "yourusername@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
  $mail->Password   = "yourpassword";            // GMAIL password

  //This is the "Mail From:" field
  $mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
  //This is the "Mail To:" field
  $mail->AddAddress('whoto@otherdomain.com', 'John Doe');
  $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), advanced';
  $mail->Body     = "Hi! \n\n This is my first e-mail sent through PHPMailer.";

  $mail->Send();
  echo "Message Sent OK<p></p>\n";
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
```

### Edit2:

The reason why you're getting this error is because you have an extra ' on your string:

Replace

```
$mail->Host = "'smtp.gmail.com";
```

with:

```
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
```

Comment: php mailer still requires sendmail setup correct?  I get the error Could not execute: /usr/sbin/sendmail when testing.

Comment: If you don't have or don't want to install Sendmail, you can configure it to use any SMTP server on the internet. Just look at the example, you need to configure `$mail-IsSMTP();` and then `$mail->Host="smtp.server.com";` . You can even use GMail to send your emails if you want. Check this: http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=exampleagmail

Comment: BTW, I would recommend using your hosting/ISP/GMail mail servers instead of setting one up. That'd be one less thing for you to configure and **maintain**.

Comment: i set up to use gmail but i get the error: Could not execute: /usr/sbin/sendmail. check it at: http://buffernet.com/phpmailer2/test/testemail.php

Comment: Try this one.
And make sure you remove the old `mail()` call you were using before from that page :)

Comment: i really appreciate the help: can you check http://buffernet.com/phpmailer2/test/testemail.php it says I can't connect to the gmail host.

Comment: Could you show us your code? It'd be hard to figure out what's wrong just by looking at the error message. Also, make sure you got all og the `$mail->SMTPAuth=true; $mail->SMTPSecure="tls"; $mail->Host="smtp.gmail.com"; $mail->Port=587;` settings correctly.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Just remove the extra ' and you should be fine :)

Comment: i removed that from both post but apparently you saw it before I edited it.  I removed it from the code and no change. Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: Any chance that your firewall is blocking the connections ?

Comment: yeah theres a chance what port would I unblock?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get mail sending up and running is to install and configure postfix.  You can use:

```
yum install postfix
```

And check out the documentation here:

```
http://www.postfix.org/docs.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [LAMPStack from BitNami](http://bitnami.org/stack/lampstack). It comes with an easy installer that installs everything you need and you'll be running in minutes.